# Difficulty in reading values Modbus application in Python(Pyserial) On Energy meter (EM6400)

Tags: python, modbus

I am trying to read energy meter(`EM6400`) voltage values in python by using modbus protocol.
But there are issues when I am reading values. I think the issue is with,
I am not reading values in proper way 
i.e. in the line ----->

`buf = ser.read(11) # reading 11 bytes from energy meter`

Here is detailed of my implementation :

Request:

```
01 03 0F56 0002 270F
01: Slave address
03: Function code for read holding registers
0F56: Data Address of the first requested register (address for voltage phase1 to neutral)
(0F56 hex = 3927, +40001 offset = 43928)
0002: Total number of registers requested
270F: CRC (Cyclic Redundancy Check) for error checking (LSB first)
```

Response:

```
01 03 04 2921 4373 D2B0
01: Slave address
03: Function code for read holding registers
04: Total number of bytes read
2921: Data in 1st requested register
4373: Data in 2st requested register
D2B0: CRC for error checking (LSB first)
```

Values in required register are `43732921` in hex (since obtained values are being read in little endian format) which is `243.16` when converted to floating point using `IEEE 754 norms`. Obtained value is a voltage (phase1 to neutral) which is `243.16` Volts.

Here is the code for the same:

```
import os
import sys
cwd=os.getcwd()
(setpath,Examples)=os.path.split(cwd)
print setpath
sys.path.append(setpath)

from PyArduino import *

import struct


port=locateport()
ser = serial.Serial(port, 9600)

ser.write("\x01\x03\x15\x86\x00\x02\x39\x15")
buf=ser.read(11)

b1=b2=b3=b4=0

a1=buf[3]

if (a1<16):
    b1=1
    a1=int(a1,16)
if (b1):
    a1='0'+str(a1)


a2=buf[4]
if (a2<16):
    b2=1
    a2=int(a2,16)
if (b2):
    a2='0'+str(a2)



a3=buf[5]
if (a3<16):
    b3=1
    a3=int(a3,16)
if (b3):
    a3='0'+str(a3)

a4=buf[6]
if (a4<16):
    b4=1
    a4=int(a4,16)
if (b4):
    a4='0'+str(a4)


a5=[a3,a4,a1,a2];
a6=''.join(a5)


print struct.unpack('!f', a6.decode('hex'))[0]
```

Comment: Have you tried using pymodbus? I used it over the weekend to read voltage values off a Morningstar charge controller and it was literally about 5 lines of code.

Comment: thanks...i haven't tried pymodbus as i want to go for pyserial module.could you please provide a sample code for the same based on pymodbus.

Comment: I copied from this guy, changed the number of registers to read to 16 (instead of 37) because I only need the bottom 16, and that was that. Pymodbus uses pyserial for serial devices. https://github.com/brocktice/tristar-python-modbus/blob/master/tristar_monitoring_serial

Comment: Let me make an answer out of that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using pymodbus instead. This is a layer that sits on top of pyserial that handles the complexities for you. It depends on twisted, but it will work without twisted for this simple case.

```
from pymodbus.client.sync import ModbusSerialClient as ModbusClient
modbus = ModbusClient(method='rtu', port='/dev/ttyUSB3', baudrate=9600, timeout=1)
modbus.connect()
r = modbus.read_holding_registers(0x0F56, 2, unit=1)
```

The data you're looking for should then be in `r.registers[0]` and `r.registers[1]`.